# Can't make an alias for an directory

Tags: apache, symfony, url-rewriting

I want to make short my URL with URL Rewriting, but i dont know how, i made reasearch but no result (url rewriting work on my server):

My url is like :

```
My-Domaine.com/Directory1/web/app.php/Directory2/    (Symfony 2 project)
```

I want to make something like this :

```
My-Domaine.com/Directory/
```

My htaccess is like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /Directory1/web/app.php/Directory2/ Directory/  [PT]
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
AuthName www.My-Domaine.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^My-Domaine.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^My-Domaine.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "3W.My-Domaine.com/Directory1/web/app.php/Directory2/" [L]
```

Sory for my english, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be easier to use an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) instead of url rewriting.

You would just need to add something like this to the host configuration.

```
Alias /Directory "var/www/Directory1/web/"
<Directory "var/www/Directory1/web/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This way you can also avoid the possibility of stepping on the URL rewriting that Symfony uses to direct requests to the front controllers.